# How to approach local database management via Flex/Air App

Tags: database, apache-flex, flash, local, data-synchronization

I am planning on using Flash Builder 4/Flex to write an AIR application which is primarily based around recording, storing and analyzing data. I'll be creating charts etc that need to update in almost real time.

It's essential to me that the application be able to function without an internet connection so I need a local database of some variety, but I would also eventually like to build in online synchronization of the data where either database can be update each other based on newer information. Moreover, some type of encryption would definitely be welcome, and speed is a large concern

Synchronization: Primarily updates/additions/deletions will be done on the offline database, but ideally I want to have a web interface that will allow the same updates/additions/deletions and will be synced (beyond that I'm not sure exactly how to do it as I can model that based on what is most achievable). I'm wondering if there's any prebuilt engine that could handle the synchronization of 2 databases. I may end up having the web interface only be for additions, which would be significantly easier to sync.. and I may start that way, but i want to build with technologies that will best allow me to implement full online crud at some point.

With all that in mind, what is my best approach to try and avoid headaches down the road?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use SQLite as described [here](http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/04/07/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air/).

Also there is a method to integrate external applications in your Air App, such as a database server or a web server.

Would you explain more details about the synchronization you're looking for?

Comment: hi .. i've added some details about what i'm thinking of in terms of sync. let me know if there are any holes still.

Answer (score 0):

While you're at it, do yourself a favor and use an ORM framework like FlexORM.
It makes persistence very easy.